# What additional or custom data can be stored in Sitecore CDP?

Tags: cdp

What parts of the `Sitecore CDP` data model are fixed? Which entities can be updated to have new additional values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Additional data can only be added to a guest in the following ways:

1. data extension on an guest
2. data extension on an order
3. data extension on an order item
4. custom event
5. an event with additional attributes

The overall structure of the Sitecore CDP data model (i.e. guests, sessions, events, orders, order Items) cannot be changed.

[image]

In addition to these options data can also be retrieved in real-time for decisioning or personalization from an external data system using a decision model. Link to documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/managing-data-systems-in-sitecore-cdp.html

Links to the documentation:

- guest data extensions:
  https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sending-additional-guest-data-to-sitecore-cdp-using-batch-api.html
- order data extensions: (for more details see:
  https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sending-additional-order-data-to-sitecore-cdp-using-batch-api.html
- order item data extensions:
  https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sitecore-cdp-order-item-extension-data-model-for-batch-api.html
- custom events: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-a-custom-event-to-sitecore-cdp.html
- events with additional attributes: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-additional-event-data-to-sitecore-cdp.html